# Upon login redirection is not happening django

Tags: python, html, django

On my localhost (127.0.0.1:8000) i have configured a Login page and upon login its not redirecting to "Automation page (form_name_view".

Note:- when i click login button nothing it happening whether with right credentials or wrong.

In views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
# Create your views here.

def login_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "post":
        username = request.post['username']
        password = request.post['password']

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('IP form'))
        else:
            context["error"] = "Provide valid credentials"
            return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)
    else:
        return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)


def form_name_view(request):              #this is the view to which i want to redirect
    if request.method == "POST":
  #some code
```

In Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Login(models.Model):



    username = models.CharField(max_length=50,)  
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32,)


    def __str__(self):                               
        return self.user.Username
```

In admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from first_app.models import Login

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Login)
```

In login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>



    <h1> Please Login</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="username">Enter username: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" required></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><label for="username">Enter password: </label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" required></td>
          </tr>
          <p> {{ error }} </p>
        </table>
        <input type="submit"  value="LOGIN"/>
          </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('Automation_page/', views.form_name_view,name='IP form'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.login_view,name='login'),
    path('first_app/',include('first_app.urls')),

    ]
```

What i want is:-
A) only the user whos username is in db should be able to access the Automation page(form_name_view)

B) when the user logs-In and successful then the must be redirected to Automation page(form_name_view) otherwise the page says and error message and stays on login page.

thnx in advance

Comment: `if request.method == 'POST'` with capitals. `request.POST['username']` with capitals.

Comment: Also don't say "nothing happens", unless the browser isn't even sending a request to your server. Always be specific, like "the page is refreshed but nothing changed" or "the page refreshes and the empty form is shown again"...

Comment: okay. my bad.! page refreshes and an empty form is given

Comment: which means `request.method` is not `"post"` (it's `"POST"`)

Comment: worked.! thnx :-)

Comment: @dirkgroten i question more. ! how can i restrict that the user should first login and then only he will be able to access the automation page. currently if the user Enters in the url "127.0.0.1/Automation_page" he cam directly access the page behind login. so how can i restrict the user to login first if the user enter the url as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the case of your strings and variables. `POST` in django is capitalised:

- It's `if request.method == 'POST'`
- It's `username = request.POST['username']`

Comment: i question more. ! how can i restrict that the user should first login and then only he will be able to access the automation page. currently if the user Enters in the url "127.0.0.1/Automation_page" he cam directly access the page behind login. so how can i restrict the user to login first if the user enter the url as above.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users)?

Comment: didnt encountered that.! btw thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading these [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-in)?
You can also try LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/dashboard' to navigate to the page of your choice after login.